# Calling C++ DLL from VBA, getting "Access violation writing location" error

Tags: c++, excel, vba, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have an Excel VBA project where I'm trying to call a function from a C++ DLL that was output from Visual Studio 2013.  I've added a reference to the DLL.  When I try to run it in the VS debugger, attached to an Excel instance where I call the DLL function using:

```
Private pw_ As Long

Private Sub class_initialize()
   pw_ = ProjectWiseAPI.CreateProjectWise(True)
End Sub
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x0EBE8536 (libProjectWise.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 
OxC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFF.
```

It breaks in this function:

```
PWAPI CreateProjectWise(LPVOID *obj, VARIANT_BOOL showErrors) {
    *obj = new XYZ_ProjectWise::ProjectWise(showErrors != FALSE);
    return S_OK;
}
```

specifically on the `*obj` assignment line.

Also, when I'm just working with the Excel file by itself, not with VS, when I compile the VBA project, I get this error:

```
File not found: T:\location\of\dll\libProjectWise.dll
```

even though I've copied the DLL, EXP, ILK, LIB, MAP, and PDB files to the `T:\location\of\dll` folder, and my ODL file contains this line:

```
[
   dllname("T:\location\of\dll\libProjectWise.dll")
]
```

I'm pretty confused by all of this.  I didn't write this API, and I've only got a rough understanding of C++ and how to develop it in Visual Studio.  The original developer is not available.

EDIT:
Here's the ODL code for the `CreateProjectWise` function:

```
[
        helpstring("Gets an instance of the API object"),
        entry("_CreateProjectWise@8")
]
HRESULT __stdcall CreateProjectWise([in] VARIANT_BOOL showErrorMessage, [out, retval] long *obj);
```

Comment: You need to show more of the IDL, in particular annotations such as `[out, retval]`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, added the ODL for this function.

Comment: See anything suspicious when you compare the ODL and the function body?  For example, parameter names and types and return type don't match?

Comment: had the wrong bracketed section with the ODL, added the correct one

Comment: Side issue: Have you tried [`dllname("T:\\location\\of\\dll\\libProjectWise.dll")`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221050%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for that C++ signature to match that call.  The C++ has two parameters, the call has only one.  And [a `[retval]` attribute is allowed only on the *last* parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221035%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), so it's not possible that `showErrors` is passed from VBA and `obj` is a buffer for the return value stored into `pw_`.

Looking at your ODL for the function, it is clear that the parameter order is reversed from the definition.  As a result the `showErrorMessage` parameter from VBA is being treated as a pointer in C++, with predictable bad results.

The MIDL compiler creates a header file when it processes ODL.  It's extremely helpful to `#include` this header file in the C or C++ code with the implementation, so that the compiler can catch issues like this automatically.

Comment: I reversed the arguments in the PWAPI definition, but now I'm getting `Can't find DLL entry point _CreateProjectWise@8` when I try to run it from the VS debugger.

Comment: @sigil: `PWAPI` definition?  The one that is something like `#define PWAPI HRESULT __stdcall __declspec(dllexport)` ?

Comment: No, I mean the `PWAPI CreateProjectWise(LPVOID *obj, VARIANT_BOOL showErrors)` that I included in my original question.  I put the `LPVOID *obj` at the end and got the `Can't find DLL entry point` as a result.

Comment: @sigil: Ahh, that's the definition of `CreateProjectWise`.  This is 32-bit compilation only, right?  Use `dumpbin /exports` to compare what functions are exported before and after rearrangement of the parameters.

Comment: The problem was that I hadn't also reversed the arguments in the function declaration in the header file `libProjectWise.h`.

Comment: @sigil yes that would be a problem. Use #include and make the compiler check those header files against the implementation. Is everything working from excel now?

Comment: It's working on my laptop, but not on the desktop that I remote into.  I think it's a dependency issue; I'll post it as a separate question.